# Collecting a List of objects into a LinkedHashMap with Java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I have a list of `Profile` objects `List<Profile> list`.

Which I need to convert into a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`.

Where object `Profile` is consisted of:

```
public class Profile {
    private String profileId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
Map<String, String> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Profile::getFirstName, 
                              Profile::getLastName));
```

But it did not work, I'm getting a compilation error:

```
Incompatible parameter types in method reference expression
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? *How* did it not work? Any error messages? What is your expected output? How is the actual output different from the the expected output?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the key-value you expect in your map?

Comment: @UjwalKumar yes, for firstName key should be "firstName", for lastName should be "lastName"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Also what do you mean by "it did not work"? Did you not get any output or error that can be useful for us to debug your problem?
Also I don't think keeping firstname as key is good idea since two people could have same first name and your stream api would give you an exception.

Comment: Well it doesnt work for example if I try to add profileId to it as well it complains `reason: Incompatible parameter types in method reference expressio`

Comment: @Sweeper Well it doesnt work for example if I try to add profileId to it as well it complains `reason: Incompatible parameter types in method reference expression*

Comment: Do you want to group the profiles under a key of `profileId`

Comment: No, just put like "firstName" which is key to Profile::getFirstName values and so on for rest in list

Comment: Maps can't have duplicate keys, so how are you going to group them?

Comment: If you have 2 profiles with first names [user1, user2], how will it look in the map? what will the keys be and what are the values

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use firstname as key. Secondly, if you could post more code, then it would be easier to replicate your issue. Currently I am unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Incompatible parameter types in method reference expression

Make sure that you're not using a list of **row type** as a stream source. I.e. check if the generic type parameter is missing: `List list` (it has to be `List<Profile> list`), otherwise all elements of the list as being of type `Object` and methods from the `Profile` class would not be accessible.

---

##### Collecting into a LinkedHashMap

By default, `toMap` provides you with a general purpose implementation of the `Map` (*for now it's* `HashMap` *but it might change in the future*).

In order to collect stream elements into a particular implementation of the `Map` interface, you need to use a flavor of [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) that expects four arguments:

- `keyMapper` - a mapping function to produce keys,
- `valueMapper` - a mapping function to produce values,
- `mergeFunction` - function that is meant to resolve collisions between value associated with the same key,
- `mapFactory` - a supplier providing a new empty Map into which the results will be inserted.

In the code below, `mergeFunction` isn't doing anything useful, it just has to be present in order to utilize the version of `toMap()` that allows to specify the `mapFactory`.

```
Map<String, String> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Profile::getFirstName,
            Profile::getLastName,
            (left, right) -> left,
            LinkedHashMap::new));
```

***Note*** if there could be cases when more than one value gets associated with the same key, you need either to provide a proper implementation of `mergeFunction` (*to peek a particular value or aggregate values, etc.*), or use `groupingBy()` as a collector, which will allow to preserve all values associated with a particular key.